# How to append to a file in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to print some data to a file with a few separate calls. I noticed that the default behaviour for a write overwrites the previously written data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void hehehaha (){
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();   
}

int main () {
  for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    hehehaha();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

this code writes only one line  `Writing this to a file.` but what I want is the following:

```
Writing this to a file.
Writing this to a file.
Writing this to a file.
```

Comment: check the `mode` argument of the ofstream `open` method

Comment: One option: open the file in append mode.

Comment: thank you very much @Kryten   and Johnny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file in `app` mode instead `myfile.open("example.txt", std::ios_base::app);`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

The default [open mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) for `ofstream` is plain `out`, which *recreates* the file from scratch (if the file exists, its contents is truncated).

To append to a file you need to use the `app` mode, or add the flag `ate`.

The table in [this `open` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) is quite helpful to understand the open-modes and what they do.

Comment: Thank you very much