# Can't write more than 1 line into file

Tags: c++

basically I'm trying to create a leaderboard with all the times of people completing a game and whenever I input a name into the console (the time is determined automatically) it sends it to the text file but it removes the first line from the file, so basically I can only have 1 person at a time and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong... anyways, here's the part of the code which I think is necessary to understand and find out my proble, if you need more of the code feel free to ask! Thanks alot

```
    cout << "Your name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    if (name.length() > 15) {
        cout << "The name length limit is 15 characters! Please try again." << endl << "Your name: ";
        if_stat(name);
    }
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    int time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count();
    ofstream myfile("C:\\Users\\guilh\\OneDrive\\Ambiente de Trabalho\\MAZE_XX_WINNERS.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        string extra = to_string(time_taken) + " - " + name;
        myfile << extra;
    }
```

Comment: Your file gets completely overwritten every time you open it. Try to open it in append mode: [How to append to a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61895932/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

This should help
Open the file in append mode instead

```
myfile.open(FILENAME, std::ios_base::app);
```