# How to choose where to send char data into a txt file

Tags: c++, file-io

I can send char data into the file, but I would like to skip like a whole paragraph of text. I need to keep a log of all of the user's moves in a game of Hangman. When the game ends and they select yes to the play again, I would hope that the text file would save the data, which it does, and then put the next round's data under it. Though it just always ends up replacing it.

I've tried a function called seekp, but I don't really know how it works and I can't seem to find out if it would help me in this case. I just want to skip the data that is already in the text file and put new stuff in it. Or even just push that preexisting data down somehow and place the new stuff at the top.

Some code:

```
    ifstream data;
    data.open("results_1.txt");
    ofstream resultsEC;
    resultsEC.open("results_EC.txt");
    char temp;

    data.get(temp);

    while (!(data.eof())) {
        results_to_results.push_back(temp);
        data.get(temp);
    }

    char temp2;

    for (int i = 0; i < results_to_results.size(); i++) {
        temp2 = results_to_results.at(i);
        resultsEC.put(temp2);
    }

    data.close();
```

Then, I recall the game() function it's in, if they choose to play again.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] of misbehaving code. Odds are you just need to [open the file for append](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61895932/364696).

Comment: After appending the file, what would I do? Is there some thing I can do to go to the bottom om the text file?

Comment: Thank you so much, appending the file was literally it. Appreciate it!